# Python: How to return a linebreak in a function

Tags: python, function, printing, return, linefeed

```
def linebreak(fruits):
    '''
    >>> fruits = 'apple banana pear'
    >>> linebreak(fruits)
    apple
    banana
    pear
    '''
    response = ''
    for fruit in fruits.split():
        response += fruit + '\n'

    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()

Expected:
    apple
    banana
    pear

Got:
    'apple\nbanana\npear\n'
```

I basically want a function that returns what print does. I hope the code is not too confusing. I have scanned the internet but all I can find is people asking questions about linefeeds when printing, not when returning.

Comment: The output **has** got linebreaks - try making the test `print linebreak(fruits)`.

Comment: You're getting confused by interactive mode's auto-print behavior. `return` and `print` do entirely different things. If you want to print something, use `print`.

Answer (score 2):

`>>> linebreak(fruits)` shows the `repr()` of the returned value, which is a Python string.

What you want is `>>> print linebreak(fruits)` which actually print the *contents* of the returned value instead of its repr:

```
>>> 'foo\nbar'
'foo\nbar'
>>> print 'foo\nbar'
foo
bar
```

---

FYI, your whole function can be simplified in one line:

```
return '\n'.join(fruits.split())
```